# Which Mass Effect 2 DLCs are relevant for Mass Effect 3's story?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-2

I'm just playing through Mass Effect 2 for the first time and loving it, and I was wondering which of the (tons and tons) of DLC for ME2 might actually be relevant for Mass Effect 3's story?

I understand that the SHADOW BROKER DLC was designed to be played at the end of ME2, with an eye for setting things up for ME3.

Is this true, and are there any other DLCs that are relevant for ME3?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Kasumi, Zaeed, Shadowbroker, Overlord, and Arrival all tie into Mass Effect 3.

The character DLC Kasumi and Zaeed, introduce new characters that have minor story arcs in the 3rd installment, with multiple outcomes based on decisions taken in Mass Effect 2.

The Shadowbroker, Overlord, and Arrival DLCs include stories and events that are referenced in Mass Effect 3 to varying degrees.

Overlord contains a minor plot referenced in ME3, Arrival is essentially a prologue to ME3,  and the Shadowbroker DLC also introduces story elements that explain a major plot point in ME3.

All the DLC's make up a large amount of content in Mass Effect 2 and will provide many additional hours of gameplay.

Comment: Arrival you can safely skip, if you're looking to save money. It's fun and all, but it doesn't have the same ramifications in ME3 as Kasumi, Zaeed, and Overlord (LotSB doesn't have as many ramifications either, but it's a helluva lot of fun and if you do it before the end of ME2 there are benefits for you in-game). 

But yeah, tiddy is right.

Comment: @jordie3000 Hey, I've just finished the game and now I'm a bit confused. You say that Arrival can be skipped, but tiddy says it's the prologue to ME3. Sounds like Arrival might be more important in that case(?).

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt - Arrival is the prologue to ME3 in the sense that where you start the game is directly due to the events in Arrival. The reason I say it's skippable is because none of the choices you make in it matter to gameplay/story in ME3. The story for ME3 assumes the events of Arrival without you actually having to do them - Shepard was there even if you weren't, whereas if you don't do LotSB Liara still gets what she wants but you weren't there to help. I mean, really, I suppose technically LotSB is the most skippable in terms of story because of that but DUDE it's so much fun.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get hung up on choices affecting the next game. They are all quite fun to play, they are their own reward. They have little to do with me3 gameplay, slightly more dialogue if even that. Overlord was cool, but hardly any reference in ME3. ME3, while a great game, does not deliver on the decisions count hype the series was built on.